# Are you a good writer? There are some prominent tag wiki excerpts which are still blank

Tags: discussion, tagging, tag-wiki-excerpts

I've written quite a lot of tag wiki excerpts and a few others have worked on them too.

But I consider myself a very bad writer plus there are a few that I'm a bit stumped as far as good wording goes.

Please add some of the missing ones. Unless you have quite high reputation you will need to go through the approval process but you will also be rewarded with some rep points when we approve them.

Try to be consistent. Look at how other tags are worded. Start with a capital letter, end with a full stop. Keep it short and avoid the words "is" and "are" early in the character sequence, also starting with "This tag", each of which may trigger an automatic tag wiki truncation algorithm which can make the [**Tags page**](https://travel.stackexchange.com/tags) look ugly.

Oh and try not to merely define the term, this is considered bad on Stack Exchange.

Here are our current most used (4 uses or more) blank tag wiki excerpts. Oh plus a few with unimaginative generic excerpts:

- [tips-and-tricks](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/tips-and-tricks) × 27
- [canada](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/canada) × 20
- [germany](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/germany) × 16
- [beaches](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/beaches) × 12
- [culture](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/culture) × 8
- [hitchhiking](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/hitchhiking) × 7
- [egypt](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/egypt) × 7
- [mongolia](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/mongolia) × 7
- [suggestions](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/suggestions) × 6 (this is probably going to be merged with "recommendations" though.
- [recommendations](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/recommendations) × 6
- [winter](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/winter) × 5
- [insects](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/insects) × 4
- [ireland](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ireland) × 4
- [language](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/language) × 4
- [new-york](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/new-york) × 4 (you probably need to consider whether it applies to the state as well as the city or not)
- [palestine](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/palestine) × 4
- [south-africa](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/south-africa) × 4
- [wildlife](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/wildlife) × 4

Comment: perhaps we can add this into the Halloween day effort :)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is a tag wiki campaign appropriate at this time?](http://meta.travel.stackexchange.com/questions/3887/is-a-tag-wiki-campaign-appropriate-at-this-time)

Comment: I added [tag:urban-exploration] a few days ago and would be grateful for peer review.  The site seems to turn off the peer review option if you have been on here for a long time.

Comment: @GayotFow: For me urban exploration is much more literal than your tag wiki. I don't restrict it to modern ruins, but everything from randomly wandering the streets of a new city up to and including modern ruins. I'm not sure if there is a specific term for modern ruins now in use in English. There is in Japanese I believe. But I'm old and out of touch (-:

Comment: The most I would do in a new city is what I call a "rec", a reconnoitre, a very brief look to see what's in a 5 minute radius, like a news stand, or a cash point, or an interesting restaurant. The problem is I don't get that many new cities. But I just learned 'urban-exploration' has a wiki entry. So I should have put the link and been done with it. (Except I like to write wiki tags).  See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Urban_exploration

Comment: @hippietrail if you spot one where I can help, ping me please, thanks

Answer (score 1):

Yes.

Assuming all the above are in use at present, they ALL have Usage guides (of some sort) at present.

Answer (score 0):

These last days I have tried to improve some descriptions and I am willing to continue. My focus has been on destination tags. I have deliberately kept the descriptions quite short. Rather than reinvesting the wheel, I have preferred to indicate links to e.g. Wikipedia, Wikitravel or some official sites.

Are there more precise out there for writing these descriptions? Or do you have a sample of some exemplary descriptions?

Comment: "... avoid the word "is", ... which will trigger an automatic tag wiki truncation algorithm which can make the Tags page look ugly"

Comment: I don't think we really have got so far as to develop our own guidelines here on travel.SE but you can find a few past meta discussions. There is surely more written somewhere about tag wikis and excerpts on one of the main sites such as Stack Overflow or on the blog... Best is to look at a few similar tags and try to be consistent with them. If you find some already inconsistent or that you're breaking new ground with nothing to compare to, then please ask specific individual questions here on meta and we'll think the issues through.